# Clipping TileLayer with georeferenced polygon (clipping mask)

Tags: openlayers, clip

I would like to add a mask to clip layers (Tile) below in a way that only the part bounded by a ol.Feature (polygon or multipolygon) is visible and the rest is hidden (left white).
The polygon is stored in a DB so I need a way to do that programatically.

Does anybody have some clues or examples to achieve this?

- ol.Overlay?
- ol.layer.Vector filled with white outside of the features

Ideally:
- add / remove vector features and interactions should update the mask
- swichting layer below the mask is possible

I'm not looking for a working code but more inspirations and ideas to start doing that in a "ol3" way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can easily be done adding an Image layer with an ImageVector source on top of the tile layer. The ImageVector layer's `precompose` and `postcompose` hooks are used to change the [global canvas composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation):

```
var clipLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      // contains your clip polygon
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      })
    })
  })
});
clipLayer.on('precompose', function(e) {
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
});
clipLayer.on('postcompose', function(e) {
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2gy96vbv/

Comment: Waw, thanks. I would never imagine that we can have a working example with less than 20 lines of codes!

Comment: @ahocevar: Is there an easy way to apply the clipping to only specific layers? e.g: clip an image layer but leave the background layers as is?

Comment: @Constantinius You may look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281164/clipping-tilelayer-with-vector-polygon-clipping-mask/281185 for a solution