# Clipping single tile layer with georeferenced polygon

Tags: openlayers, clip

I have very similar question to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185881/clipping-tilelayer-with-georeferenced-polygon-clipping-mask). The difference is I would like to clip only one layer that is not a base layer. I like the solution purposed in mentioned question, but unfortunately it clips all layers.

Does any one have any clue how to achieve this?