# Clipping TileLayer with vector polygon (clipping mask)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, clip, rendering

I would like to add a mask to clip layer (Tile) in a way that only the part bounded by a ol.Feature (polygon or multipolygon or layer) is visible and the rest is hidden (left transparent). The geometry is generated dynamically so I need a way to do that programatically.

I presented the question [Clipping TileLayer with georeferenced polygon (clipping mask)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185881) ([see](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbopre4/1/)).
Clipping map with vector layer (only layers zIndex == 0):

```js
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'black'
  })
});

var clipLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '//openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: style
  })
});
clipLayer.on('postcompose', function(e) {
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
clipLayer.on('precompose', function(e) {
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
});
```

Example result: OSM (BaseLayer), TileLayer (Stamen) and vector layer

[image: World map with a clipped overlay on Australia]

Two layers were clipped (!) - OSM and TileLayer.

I need clipping TileLayer with vector layer (support zIndex).
Example: OSM (BaseLayer), TileLayer and vector layer

[image: Australia map with a clipped overlay on South Australia]

One layer were clipped - TileLayer.

Does anybody have some clues or examples to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You will find [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/5bf03d9c2acaa4562fecb94aadfb04e4) to do this using `ol.source.Raster`, quickly illustrated with an animated GIF.

[image: Filter a particular layer with a vector source]

I'm using it to combined an `ol.source.ImageVector` with an `ol.source.Stamen` (for this demo but any raster `ol.source.*` would work)
FYI, the function `ol.source.ImageVector` is normally deprecated but with the new recommanded way, I don't see how to do it as I can't access to a source to mix both raster and vector layers sources within `ol.source.Raster`. (any clue is welcome to upgrade)

**Solution 2:**

Use an OpenLayers ol-ext plugin, see the [demo](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html) that do more or less the same as solution 1 I've done (but I didn't look how it's done)

Comment: Thank you. Although "ol-ext" solves the problem